# How to show a popup through javascript just on the first page load of the session?

Tags: javascript

we would like to show a popup advertising of an iphone app on our website to users that browse with the applo mobile devices.

We already achieve it, but now we need to show only on the first page load of the user session, so it wouldn't be disruptive on every page load.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Set a cookie and only show the popup is this cookie does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a cookie? Do something like

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['firstVisit'])){
    //Show popup (maybe echo some JS)

    $inTwoMonths = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60 + time(); 
    setcookie('firstVisit', 'blah', $inTwoMonths); 
}else {
    //Do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can do this:

(1) Add a variable in the session itself which indicates as to whether the pop-up should be displayed or not.

(2) Alternatively, as suggested you could set a cookie and take appropriate step depending upon the cookie value.

Hope this helps.